# What is the git command to create a branch based on the upstream master?

Tags: git

When I've made some commits to my local master branch, but not pushed them. And then I want to create another branch before I push those commits, but the other branch should not include those commits in its history, but rather be based on the clean upstream master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout -b <new branch name> origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the upstream master with `git checkout origin/master` and then create a branch via `git branch <branchname>`

You would also be able to checkout a specific SHA on your local and create a branch there with `git checkout -b <branchname> <SHA of commit>`.  This is useful if you decide that you also need to have one of the commits that you made on the new branch.